# Punctuation of a sentence that starts with a question and ends with a declaration

Tags: punctuation, question-mark

I'll provide the sentence and some context.

> There is still so much that I do not know about college. How do I pay
>   bills, which classes should I take, what do TA's do, how to write a
>   college essay, and so many more questions

Do I end the last sentence with a question mark or a period?

Comment: Rephrase your question like this - `There is still so much that I do not know about college like how do I pay bills, which classes should I take, what do TA's do, how to write a college essay, and many more.`

Comment: Technically you are quoting several questions inside your sentence.  You could literally quote them, with question marks at the end of each, but (if you insist on using this form vs one of the suggested alternatives) leaving out the question marks entirely is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

If you were writing this sentence from scratch, it would be preferable to reword it so as to avoid the punctuation problem. For example:

> There is still so much that I do not know about college. How do I pay
>   bills?Which classes should I take? What do TA's do? How do I write a
>   college essay? And so on.

However, we're sometimes called upon to transcribe a spoken statement, where it's not permitted to change the wording, and the punctuation must reflect the intention and even tone of the speaker as faithfully as possible. This is a challenging task at the best of times! One possible approach to your example would be to make the questioning implicit, without using a question mark; for example:

> There is still so much that I do not know about college: how do I pay
>   bills, which classes should I take, what do TA's do, how to write a
>   college essay - and so many more questions.

Finally, you could stand your ground against the grammar police and invoke a very old-fashioned usage that allowed question marks *within* a sentence, as if there were an invisible comma following each:

> There is still so much that I do not know about college. How do I pay
>   bills? which classes should I take? what do TA's do? how to write a
>   college essay, and so many more questions.

[Note that "how to write a college essay" is not a question, so it doesn't need to be treated like the previous clauses].

For a great example of this old approach, see William Blake's *[The Tyger](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/43687)*, one verse of which is

> What the hammer? what the chain, / In what furnace was thy brain? /
>   What the anvil? what dread grasp, / Dare its deadly terrors clasp!